# MYSQL: Using column name in CONCAT() function gives syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have this query

```
UPDATE `fitment_drums` SET `liters` = CONCAT(`liters`,'.0') WHERE `liters` LIKE '_'
```

Which results in this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''.0') FROM `fitment_drums` WHERE `liters` LIKE '_'' at line 1

When I substitute an ordinary string, eg. `CONCAT ('asdf','.0')` it works fine. I've tried using a select statement as an argument, and have also tried using a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (SELECT * FROM `fitment_drums` WHERE liters like '_') 
UPDATE `fitment_drums` SET liters = CONCAT(t1.liters,'.0') where t1.id = id
```

Comment: Is liters a numeric field ?

Comment: It's a varchar field.

Comment: You don't have a semicolon following your CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: @grahamj42 Why would that matter for a syntax error? Why would it matter at all, since MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings when used with `CONCAT()`?

Comment: The error isn't coming from the query you showed. The error message says the query contains `FROM \`fitment_drums\` `, but that's not anywhere in that query.

Comment: Perhaps mysql doesn't know what `liters` is (inside de concat)
I mean, liters could be anything, and you are using it as a variable. You and I both know it is a field in a table, but `CONCAT()` doesn't know that.

Comment: @BillKarwin I've omitted the semicolons from the code

Comment: @Barmar you're right, "FROM..." is nowhere in the query, but the query I posted does give this error.

Comment: But we need to see the correct query so we can match "near XXX" with what's in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found the "solution". I was running the query in simulation mode, which results in the error posted above. So I backed up the table and executed the query in live mode, and it worked. (for the record, I'm using phpMyAdmin)

Very strange.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you revealed that you're using phpMyAdmin, you should know that temporary tables are dropped automatically as a database connection ends.

Each page view in phpMyAdmin is a separate PHP request, and thus a separate database connection.

So if you `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` in phpMyAdmin, then the temp table did not exist anymore by the time you ran your `UPDATE`.